# Does a bounded function necessarily have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If f is defined on A ⊆ R to R, c is a cluster point of A, and f is bounded on a neighborhood of c, does this mean that f has a limit L ∈ R at c?

Comment: $f$ has the potential to be evaluated for a limit at $c$; that doesn't mean it has a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider Dirichlet function

$D(x) = 1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $D(x)=0$ otherwise.

This function is bounded ($0\leq D(x)\leq 1$), but it does not have a limit at any point because every open interval contains rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: Aside: while this gives a counterexample for most $A$, it's maybe worth noting that there are choices of $A$ where limits of the restriction of $D$ to $A$ would exist, such as $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: you are right, but I'll leave it to the OP to find a modification of this function which will work for other $A$'s

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

consider the  function $$y=\begin {cases}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \quad \mbox{for}\quad x\ne 0\\
0 \quad \mbox{for}\quad x= 0\end{cases}$$
with $c=0$